# T4 template whitespace control

Tags: t4

Are there any commands to easily control T4 template output whitespace? I'm getting some excessive tabbing. I thought I remembered a way to control template whitespace...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PushIndent, PopIndent, ClearIndent http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126474.aspx

Do not format your template for readability. Any white space you have outside of  control block will end up in the output

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) 
{
   #>
     Hello
    <#
}
```

will end up as

```
   Hello
      Hello
      Hello
      Hello
      Hello
      Hello
```

Comment: "Do not format your template for readability" makes me very sad. :(

Comment: See Josh.M's answer below. The place where you put the directives determines the starting point of the generation. Keep them at position 0 to gain more control. Also if there is no text AFTER a directive, it can affect your newlines. Formatting template output is very well possible, but takes a ton of effort. I prefer to do it however, because it saves time while debugging when I'm creating a new template.

Answer (score 4):

There's probably no great fix to this, it's a problem with the T4 engine itself, IMO. But if you're trying to reduce leading tabs/spaces in your output while preserving directive nesting you can do the following.

**Before**

```
<# for (...) { #>
    <# if (...) { #>
        SomeText
    <# } #>
<# } #>
```

**After**

```
<# for (...) { #>
<#     if (...) { #>
        SomeText
<#     } #>
<# } #>
```

E.g. start your directives at column 0, indent within the directive itself! In addition to this, you may want to trim extra lines:

```
private void TrimExtraneousLineBreaksAfterCommentsFromGeneratedFile(ref string fileText)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"(//.+?)(?:\r?\n){2,}");

    // Replace multiple coniguous line breaks, after a comment, with a single line break.
    fileText = regex.Replace(fileText, "\r\n");
}

private void TrimExtraneousLineBreaksFromGeneratedFile(ref string fileText)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\r?\n(?:\s*?\r?\n)+");

    // Replace multiple coniguous line breaks with 2 line breaks.
    fileText = regex.Replace(fileText, "\r\n\r\n");

    // Remove spaces/line breaks from the file.
    fileText = fileText.Trim();
}
```

*YMMV*

Answer (score 2):

just incase someone is looking adding tabs using writeLine method. The escape character works.

```
<#
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) 
{
  this.WriteLine("\tHello");
}
#>
```